# EF code first and virtual properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have two tables `Articles` and `Events` and I'd like to provide a commenting functionality to the users on both types. The hard part is that I'd like to use a navigation property that returns the comments belonging to the given EF object.

```
public class Article
{
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    /* more properties here */
}

public class Event
{
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    /* more properties here */
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentAt { get; set; }

    public int TargetId { get; set; }
    public CommentTargeType TargetType { get; set; }
}

public enum CommentTargeType
{
    Article,
    Event
}
```

As you see the `TargetId` would be the id of the `Article` or of the `Event` and the `TargetType` is to distinguish these two types.
So, is there any way to do this? Or would it be better to create an ArticleComments and an EventComments type instead?

Comment: What you have will work, you just have to be careful on your read and writes that the TargetType is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current design is essentially using the same field in your object to be a foreign key into 2 tables. I would advise against that because the database won't be able to force any constraints or do integrity checks.

You can add two `int?` fields, one called ArticleId and one called EventId to accomplish what you want. Since the types are `int?` they will be nullable fields in the database.

I would even go one step farther and use the `ForeignKey` attribute so that EntityFramework knows about this and creates the foreign keys for you.

```
[ForeignKey("Article")]
public int? ArticleId { ... }
public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Event")]
public int? EventId { get; set; }
public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
```

Comment: "the database won't be able to force any constraints or do integrity checks" - this is a great insight